# Magento 2.4.2: how to add some charge(such as handling charge) to the FedEx shipping cost in the checkout page?

Tags: checkout, event-observer, magento2.4.2, fedex, rules

I would need to add some additional charge to the shipping cost shown by FedEx in the checkout page. In order to do this with custom code, I would like to know if there is an Magento event that gets triggered just before the checkout page is rendered. If yes, what is the event that I need to look into so that I can add charge to the shipping. This additional charge is based on some rules(using values present in an SQL table). I found an event `checkout_cart_update_items_after`, but this works only if cart page is visited not if user goes directly to the checkout page. Note: the shipping cost gets displayed only after entering the zipcode.

If there is another way to achieve this, please suggest me on going about it. Thank you

[image]

Comment: No magento doesn't have any in built extension like this one, buit there are other free extension you can use like this one : https://magecomp.com/magento-2-extra-fee.html

Comment: This extension doesn't seem to handle duty on international orders.

Comment: You need to do some customization, so it will do it accordingly.

Comment: OKay, you mean customization after installing this extension?

Comment: yes, you need to do for the countries.

Comment: We are only planning to ship to Canada. We are serving US primarily. Canada is the second country we want o ship to.

Comment: Dhiren, please check my edited post.